# how to remove particular folder name from URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have an URL :

http://localhost/HeapShop/admin/pages/create-users.php/

I need to change this URL to :

https://localhost/heapshop/admin/create-users.php/

Need to remove pages (Folder Path) from URL.

Comment: You are using different spelling for "HeapShop" here. Is that desired, so do you also need to rewrite that? Otherwise please revise your question. Thanks.

Comment: Apart from that it is hard to guess what your real requirement is: is it really just this single URL you want to rewrite? If so, what is the actual issue you face? You need to implement a single rule. You will find thousands if examples for that here on SO and in the documentation of apache's rewriting module. If you cannot derive your rule from that you need to tell us why not, so that we can help in a specific way.

Comment: No its a mistake...actual url also heapshop not in caps

Comment: Then I would suggest that you change it in the question. Thanks.